# JavaScript split long string into array based on div height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a long string that I am trying to display a `div`.

My Target:

I am trying to split that large string into array on the basis of the number of words that I can display in div (decided on the basis of width and height).

Code:

```
    data1 = data1.split(" "); // data1 is the original string, here I am obtaining words
    const len = data1.length;

    const wordcount = 105; // 105 is hard-coded that I am tying to automate 105 means div will have only 105 words and below I am storing 105 words in page array at each index 
    let page = []
    for (let i = 0; i < (len / wordcount); i++) {
        page.push(data1.slice(wordcount * i, wordcount * (i + 1)).join(" "))
    }
```

I have added the code below when I am displaying text from `page[0]` and `page[1]` `page[0]` has properly filled the div but not `page[1]`, Problem is that I can't figure out how to decide word count for each index of the page so that it completely fill the div box.

I am trying to create a custom text reader that is why I am doing this.

```js
let data = "dfgdfgdf gdfg dfsdfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdf dfgdfgdfgdfgd fgdfgdfgdfg d fg df g dfg df gdf g dfgdfg dfgdfgdfdfgdfgdf gdfg dfsdfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdf dfgdfgdfgdfgd fgdfgdfgdfg d fg df g dfg df gdf g dfgdfg dfgdfgdfdfgdfgdf gdfg dfsdfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdf dfgdfgdfgdfgd fgdfgdfgdfg d fg df g dfg df gdf g dfgdfg dfgdfgdf"

let width = $('#box').width()
let height = $('#box').height()

// now based on above width and height I am trying to create a function that will tell how many words I can use to split text it can be same words on each index or variable - this what I am unable to think

let wordcount = 8; // let say I get 8 from some algo 

let data1 = data.split(" ");
const len = data1.length;
let page = []
for (let i = 0; i < (len / wordcount); i++) {
  page.push(data1.slice(wordcount * i, wordcount * (i + 1)).join(" "))
        }

$("#data").text(page[0]+"")

$("#data1").text(page[1]+"")
```

```css
.abc {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 130px;
  height: 105px;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="abc" id="box">
<p id="data"></p>
</div>

<div class="abc">
<p id="data1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what the question is - you want to paginate based on word count? If str is `a b c ... z` and word count is `3`, you want pages to be `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], ..., [y, z]]`? Or something else?

Comment: @LionelRowe I have update my code snippet  and question.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now — you want to paginate based on physical space taken up by the words? This is doable if a) the pagination is done purely on the front end or b) the text is in a monospace font with no extra-wide characters such as 丁, , or ‱. If _neither_ a) nor b) are true, this will be next-to-impossible. Can you confirm which is the case?

Comment: @LionelRowe yes front end and only text, basically it will be html but I will figure it out later how to add images and table etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to compare the `bottom` property of `DOMRect`s obtained with [`Element#getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), taking `padding` into account. `DOMRect`s can only be obtained for elements, not text alone, so we first need to wrap all the words in `span`s.

Note that each time this code runs, it will overwrite the contents of the `#page` element. If you want to calculate pagination *without* doing that, you'll need to clone the element and render an invisible (`opacity: 0`) version with the same width and height. I haven't done that here to keep things relatively simple.

```js
// utils
const mod = (n, modulus) => ((n % modulus) + modulus) % modulus
const last = arr => arr.slice(-1)[0]

// elements
const page = document.querySelector('#page')
const paginator = document.querySelector('#paginator')
const pageCount = document.querySelector('#page-count')

// best to set these in the JS to make sure the values line up when calculating distance from bottom
const [paddingY, paddingX] = [20, 15]
page.style.padding = [paddingY, paddingX].map(n => `${n}px`).join(' ')

// main logic
const createWordSpans = text => text
    .split(/(\s+)/)
    .map((str, idx) => {
        if (!str) return null

        if (idx % 2) {
            return document.createTextNode(str)
        } else {
            const span = document.createElement('span')
            span.textContent = str

            return span
        }
    })
    .filter(Boolean)

// note that this rewrites the content of the element
const paginateByBoundingElement = parent => text => {
    parent.textContent = ''
    const { bottom } = parent.getBoundingClientRect()

    const pages = [[]]

    for (const node of createWordSpans(text)) {
        parent.appendChild(node)

        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()

            if (rect.bottom + paddingY > bottom) {
                pages.push([node.textContent])
                parent.textContent = ''
                parent.appendChild(node)
            } else {
                last(pages).push(node.textContent)
            }
        } else {
            last(pages).push(node.data)
        }
    }

    return pages.map(page => page.join(''))
}

// getContent() just returns a string - see below
const pages = paginateByBoundingElement(page)(getContent())

page.textContent = pages[0]
pageCount.textContent = pages.length

paginator.addEventListener('input', e => {
    if (!e.currentTarget.value.length) return

    const newPageIdx = mod((parseInt(e.currentTarget.value) || 0) - 1, pages.length)
    const humanFriendly = String(newPageIdx + 1)
    
    page.textContent = pages[newPageIdx]
    page.dataset.page = humanFriendly
    
    e.currentTarget.value = humanFriendly
})

function getContent() {
    return `In the northern ocean there is a fish, called the Kun, many thousand li in size. This Kun changes into a bird, called the Peng, whose back is many thousand li in breadth. With a mighty effort it rises, and its wings obscure the sky like clouds.\n\nAt the equinox, this bird prepares to start for the southern ocean, the Celestial Lake. And in the Record of Marvels we read that when the Peng flies southwards, the water is smitten for a space of three thousand li around, while the bird itself mounts upon a typhoon to a height of ninety thousand li, for a flight of six months' duration.\n\nJust so are the motes in a sunbeam blown aloft. For whether the blue of the sky is its real colour, or only the result of distance without end, the effect to the bird looking down would be just the same as to the motes.`
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page {
    width: 12em;
    height: 15em;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    position: relative;
}

#page::after {
    content: attr(data-page);
    color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

#paginator {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" data-page="1"></div>

<br>

<label>Page <input id="paginator" type="number" step="1" value="1"> of <span id="page-count">1</span></label>
```

Comment: Thanks now I have the idea how to do it.